# How do I make a radiobutton look like a toggle button?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

Windows Phone 7: How do I make a radiobutton look like a toggle button? 
I am trying to get the selected radio button to look like a depressed button.

Basically I have a filter by 'FName', 'LName' radio button over my list of names. RadioButton takes up too much screen space. A depressed button will save the space used by the 'O'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing your Xaml to specify a ToggleButton which is the base class for RadioButtons and CheckBox's, but since it is a ToggleButton you will have to interlock them in the `Checked` and `UnChecked` events. See this [article](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-ToggleButton-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx) and this [MSDN information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612601%28v=vs.95%29). Your only other option would be to create a new [Style for your RadioButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296247%28VS.95%29.aspx).

**From:**

```
<RadioButton  Content="First Name" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,92,0,0" Name="FName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" />
```

**To:**

```
<ToggleButton Content="First Name" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,92,0,0" Name="FName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" />
```

Comment: Bottom line: just use the ToggleButton class.

Comment: @DennisDelimarsky Yes you could summarize it as that, I did want the OP to be aware that ToggleButton behavior is different than RadioButton behavior and he will need to do his own interlocking.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this if you overwrite the template radio button.

In WPF, we can use the following "hack":

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
```

I believe that this does not work for WP7.
I suggest you create your own style of 0.
You can use the Expression Blend to facilitate your work. Look about writing styles that should help.